# flutter_webview crashes when height over 2048 on Android devices

Tags: flutter, webview, crash, flutter-web, android-virtualdisplay

I am trying to display articles on my flutter app from the web, so I am using flutter_webview wrapped into a container that takes the height of the page from the JavaScript onPageFinished, the height can be too big and causes the app to crash, for now I beleive there is still no solution for this as it's shown in here [#28978](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28978).

did you have this issue too? It would really help if there are any workarounds that can temporarely solve this issue!

The app only crashes on Android. It works pretty fine on iOS